# How do I design a hash function for this given case?

Tags: algorithms, hash-function

My professor gave me the following problem.

> You are to store objects identified by integers from the interval
>   $[0..10^9 − 1]$. You expect never to have to store more than 1400
>   objects. Design the hash function h of the type discussed in class
>   (universal hashing). That is, select a prime number on which the hash
>   function will be based, the ”dimensionality” of your hash funciton,
>   say k, and k parameters $\{ a_0, . . . , a_{k−1}\}$. Given your selections, what
>   is $h(350620501)$? Explain all choices you made.

I've developed the following answer.

> Generate a prime number p that is greater than the range of keys that
>   the objects in the table will be identified by $[0…(10^9-1)]$. The
>   first prime greater than $10^9$ will do for this example, so let
>   $p = 1000000007$.
>   Because the data type to be hashed are integers, two randomly
>   generated integers modulo p are chosen to add randomness to the
>   hash function, so let $a = 63873076$ and $b = 87191394$. The number
>   of slots in the table will be the maximum number of objects we will
>   be expecting to store, so let $m = 1400$. The universal hash
>   function will be defined as:
>
> $h(x) = ((ax + b) \mod p) \mod m$
>
> $h(350 620 501) = 7$

This is my first time generating a hash function, so I wanted to ensure that my solution and understanding was correct--specifically, my thinking behind choosing the value for m and the reason that values a and b are added to the function.

Comment: Use `$10^9$` to get "$10^9$" and in general google for StackExchange LaTeX guide to see how to write all math expressions. Your reasoning is fine.

Comment: First time using LaTeX. Thanks for the pointer to the guide.

Comment: I should mention that it depends on what kind of hashing you are using. It's fine if you use a linked list for each hash value, which is always what you should use anyway.